# Is there any reason for saying "he is good-looking", instead of "he is well-looking"?

Tags: word-usage, compound-adjectives

A person who has............is said to be..............

> - "good manners".........."well-mannered"
> - "good behaviour"........"well-behaved"
> - "good intentions"........"well-intentioned"
> - "a good reputation"....."well-thought-of"
> - "a good upbringing"...."well-bred"
> - "a good education"......"well-educated"
> - "a good proportion"....."well-proportioned"
> - "a good taste"..............."well-tasted"

But someone who has "good looks" is said to be "good-looking".  Would it be wrong to say "well-looking"?

Comment: *well-tasted*? *well-cooked food* is idiomatic, and a *well-done steak*, passable but a *well-tasted wine*? No. That would be a [*good-tasting*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/good-tasting) wine

Comment: @Mari-LouA I mean a person who has good taste.

Comment: Still wrong, someone can have "good taste in clothes", but they can't be "well-tasted dressed", instead they are "well-dressed". Hey, wait and see if anyone else picks up on this.

Comment: well-tasted adjective (now rare) (a) having a good taste or flavour; (b) (of a person) having good taste    http://www.seadict.com/en/en/well(2)

Comment: First time, I've heard of "well-tasted" I still wouldn't use it.

Comment: Your question stems from a misunderstanding: _good-looking_ does not mean ‘who has good looks’ (that would, as your examples, yield the nonexistent _*well-looked_ if turned into an attributive adjective through the means of a past participle); it means ‘who looks good’. Same as how the wine that tastes good is _good-tasting_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Nor would I.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It is perhaps a natural mistake for Luis to make, given that Romance and Germanic languages form these sorts of compounds involving a verb and a complement in the opposite order of each other.

Comment: Your parallel isn't quite right. It ought to be "good looks" to "well-looked" if you followed the same conversion. In fact, that might tell us something very interesting, as *good* + complement seems to take a gerund, where *well* + complement seems to take a past participle. I don't have any idea if that's true or not though.

Comment: @KitFox  I see. You're right about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason one says *good-looking* is because someone **looks good**.

This is just the same reason why it’s *nice-sounding* for sounding nice, *sweet-smelling* for smelling sweet, *good-tasting* for tasting good, *bird-watching* for watching birds, *acid-producing* for producing acid, *bear-baiting* for baiting bears, or even a *claim-jumper* for someone who jumps claims and a *skyscraper* for a tall building that scrapes the skies.

In all cases, the predicate complement, which normally follows the finite verb, becomes here the hyphenated prefix falling before the *-ing* word when the verbal phrase gets used adjectivally.  Normally these complements are direct objects (and thus substantives) of transitive verbs, but for the sense verb, they are adjectives.

The Romance languages do not form compound words using this sort of inversion of verb and object.  So where English has *skyscraper*, Spanish has *rascacielos*, Portuguese has *arranha-céu*, French has *gratte-ciel*, Italian has *grattacielo*, and Catalan has *gratacel* or *tocanúvols*.  Here the complement follows the verb, whereas in English, it precedes it.

Comment: Addition: they're normally direct objects, _or_ subject complements for linking verbs (nice-seeming, harsh-appearing, etc.). Note that English does have a few compounds that work in the ‘Romance’ way, the most widely discussed example being _pickpocket_. There is [a whole PhD thesis](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/handle/1887/18706) about them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It hardly seems fair that pickpockets and nitpickers should hang out at opposite ends of the connective spectrum. Obviously the pocketpickers are trying to disguise their nefarious activities by using a nonstandard ordering. :)

Answer (score 7):

**"well-looking"** is the opposite of sick-looking, "good-looking" the opposite of ugly-looking.

Answer (score 2):

When we say “he means well” and “he is well-meaning”, “well” is an adverb modifying the verb “mean”. When we say “he looks good” and “he is good-looking”, “good” is not an adverb but an adjective used as a predicate complement, as in “he is good”, or “the food tastes good”.In “he looks well” and “he is well-looking”, “well” is not the adverb from “good” but the adjective “well” = “healthy”. So here too we have a predicate complement, not an adverb.

Comment: In that case, why don't we say "He is good-mannered?

Comment: Because there is no verb "to manner". Here "well" is an adverb modifying an adjective.

Comment: To paraphrase you, when we say "he has good intentions", good is not an adverb, but an adjective used as a predicate complement. However, contrary to what you said, when we form the compound-adjective, we use the adverb "well".

Comment: No, "good" in "good intentions" is an attributive adjective, not a predicate.

Comment: I got confused here. I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

No, looking well means that one is looking healthy. Many would say that good looks means that one is healthy, but generally when used in that way, it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking is a "gerund" (an -ing verb used as a noun). Hence, it is modified by the adjective good, rather than the adverb well. In your other examples with "well," (mannered, behaved, etc.), it modified verbs (in the past tense).

Comment: "Good-looking" is not a noun but an adjective.

Comment: @fdb: Yes, the combined word "goodlooking" is an adjective. But individually, looking is still the noun, and good is the adjective.

Comment: In this context "looking" is the present participle of the verb "to look", i.e., an adjective.